# Read() Write() commands producing unwanted resource id #9

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, libssh2, net-ssh

I am attempting to run some ping commands on a server with read() and write() commands. I am using the phpseclib connected to Net_ssh2 but when I try to get the results and see what is happening in the echo $this->ssh->getLog();

Here is the ssh into the router:

```
$this->ssh->write('ssh '.$this->userid.'@'.$this->testIPAddress);
$this->ssh->write("\n");
$this->ssh->read('Password:');      
$this->ssh->write($this->passwd);
$this->ssh->write("\n");
$this->ssh->read('Welcome');
```

From there I get the success message that I logged into that router so then I run the following ping command:

```
 $this->ssh->write("ping 172.11.1.221");
 $this->ssh->write("\n");
 $testLineShowResult = $this->ssh->read('Type');
```

This is what the log returns:

```
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:34                       ........4

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0022, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0018, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:9c:52:65:73:6f:75:72:63:65  ........Resource
00000010  20:69:64:20:23:39:52:65:73:6f:75:72:63:65:20:69   id #9Resource i
00000020  64:20:23:39:52:65:73:6f:75:72:63:65:20:69:64:20  d #9Resource id 
00000030  23:39:52:65:73:6f:75:72:63:65:20:69:64:20:23:39  #9Resource id #9
00000040  52:65:73:6f:75:72:63:65:20:69:64:20:23:39:70:69  Resource id #9pi
00000050  6e:67:20:31:37:32:2e:31:20:20:20:5e:36:2e:31:2e  ng 172.1   ^6.1.
00000060  32:35:34:0d:0a:0d:0a:25:20:49:6e:76:61:6c:69:64  254....% Invalid
00000070  20:69:6e:70:75:74:20:64:65:74:65:63:74:65:64:20   input detected 
00000080  61:74:20:27:5e:27:20:6d:61:72:6b:65:72:2e:0d:0a  at '^' marker...
00000090  0d:0a:69:62:63:5f:34:35:37:39:33:30:30:39:30:37  ..ibc_4579300907
000000a0  5f:63:65:3e                                      _ce>
```

As you can see it prints resource id #9 a bunch of times... does anyone know why? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I Google'd "*invalid input detected at '^' marker*" and found this:

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/28616

Quoting it,

```
On the switch you are connected to, does the prompt look similar to this:

switch>

If so, we need to type in "enable" to go into privileged mode, where the prompt will look like this:

switch#
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is it because I can run the ping command in putty with the current mode with no issue. I believe it has to do with the Phpseclib in some way...

Comment: @LeeBronwin - What are you using for your router? Could you post the full SSH logs? Maybe on pastebin.com or something? Your post has `Resource id #9` repeated four times and then appears to be attempting to echo out the command. It's doing `ping 172.1   ^6.1.254`. It's almost like the second 1 in that second octet is being replaced with "   ^6". Kinda makes me think maybe some character is being sent that looks like a `1` but isn't. It's not echo'ing any character like that back but maybe it wouldn't..  and your SO post text doesn't have any character like that in it but maybe SO removed it..